# Pass table names from a file to oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a workflow in `oozie`. In this workflow I want to pass a table name as an argument. The table names are present in a file `tables.txt`
I want to pass the table names from `tables.txt` to the workflow.

```
<workflow-app name="Shell_test" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
<start to="shell-8f63"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="test_shell">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <exec>shell.sh</exec>
        <argument>${table}</argument>
        <env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=${wf:user()}</env-var>
        <file>/user/oozie/lib/test_shell.sh#shell.sh</file>
        <file>/user/oozie/input/tables.txt#tables.txt</file>
    </shell>
    <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="email-error"/>
    </action>
    <action name="email-error">
    <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.2">
        <to>xxxxxxxxxx.com</to>
        <subject>Status of workflow ${table}</subject>
        <body>The workflow ${table} ${wf:id()} had issues and was killed. The error message is: ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}</body>
        <content_type>text/plain</content_type>
    </email>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="end"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

I was able to do this using the following in the workflow.

```
<argument>${input_file}</argument>
<env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=${wf:user()}</env-var>
<file>/user/oozie/lib/test_shell.sh#shell.sh</file>
<file>/user/oozie/input/${input_file}#${input_file}</file>
```

Now I have a problem.

Say If the workflow fails for one of the tables in the `input_file` then I am not getting any email. I am getting email only if the workflow fails for the last table in the `input_file`.

Why is this happening and How can I get an email for every time the workflow fails?

Or am I doing the whole process wrong.

Could anyone please explain and correct me where I am doing things in a wrong way.

My `test_shell.sh`

```
while read line ;do 
     spark-submit --name "SparkJob" --master "yarn-client" test.py $line 
done < tables.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell action will not behave as shh action, as the shell action workflow will run on one of the data nodes it will treat the script errors as warnings until and unless you do **exit 1** inside your script. The other way to receive emails on failure is using the email utility inside the script, something like this before doing **exit 1** `echo 'script X returned an error due to some reason; Please check the workflow for validation' |  mailx -r oozie -s 'SUBJECTTOEMAIL' email@someemail.com` to make the email utility work from data node make sure your data nodes have the email utility installed. If not installed you can do ssh on the email part to your edge node which looks something like this `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${edgeUser}@${edgeHost} "echo 'script X returned an error due to some reason; Please check the workflow for validation' |  mailx -r oozie -s 'SUBJECTTOEMAIL' email@someemail.com"`

I can suggest you some changes to your workflow which might give you better results on reflecting the errors and utilizing the email action in the workflow

Don't call the config file from the shell action itself, instead, you can do as below

```html
<workflow-app name="Shell_test" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
<start to="shell-8f63"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="test_shell">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <exec>shell.sh</exec>
        <env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=${wf:user()}</env-var>
        <file>/user/oozie/lib/test_shell.sh#shell.sh</file>
        <file>/user/oozie/input/tables.txt</file>
    </shell>
```

If you notice the changes I made to your workflow, I'm just calling the tables.txt as a file instead of actually making it as an execution by removing the #tables.txt

When you do that what happens is shell action will actually copy that file and store in the container that it is running, so to utilize the table.txt config file, inside the script you will call like this `. ./tables.txt` because the container has already copied so you can call the tables.txt as it is in the home directory.

Hopefully, this will help you...!!! please comment if you have any questions on the solution I've suggested.

Comment: @Intrested_user Can you please elobarate it ?? which email action ?? did you tried using from the script or you are referring to shell email action ? if you are referring to oozie email action did you tried using my workflow.xml suggestion or using the one in your question ?

Comment: @Intrested_user ASSUMING that you are referring to oozie email action : [table] cannot be resolved because the email action is different from your shell action which is executing the script. you are passing the variable in your script action, as email action is different action it cannot recognize the ${table} parameter.

Comment: You can do that by doing the echo of your tables.txt in the script and at the end of the shell action you will capture the output with this <capture-output/> so when the output is captured you should be able to use it as a parameter in the email action.

Comment: @Intrested_user I don't have the code mentor account sorry.. can you tell me in steps wise what your script will do may be I can help you that way

Comment: Ok, My suggestion in that case is to depend on the script instead of the oozie email action. That way you can even exit your script with exit 1. The main reason for suggesting this is she'll action will not always send you emails as accurate as ssh action because it runs through data nodes.